# Azure Virtual Machine and local scanner

Tags: azure, device, printers

I am using a Virtual Machine on Azure, based on Windows Server 2012.

Depending on where I connect from, I correctly see the local printers when I try to print something.

Is there any way to see in the device list of the server a USB scanner locally connected to the user client and use it in the server?

Thank you very much,
Fabio